# vb.net Reading from a .txt file and displaying the contents

Tags: vb.net, file, streamreader

I'm making a simple program which reads and writes .txt files. I've got the program to write to and save a .txt file however I'm having some trouble reading from .txt files. Here's what I've got so far:

```
Using openTxt As New OpenFileDialog()
    If openTxt.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim displayForm As New Form
        Dim textReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(openTxt.FileName)
        displayForm.ListBox1.Text = textReader.ReadToEnd
        textReader.Close()
        displayForm.Show()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Not a text file")
    End If
End Using
```

What I would like to happen is when the text has been read it populates in a list box which is present inside another form (displayForm). I've tried getting the text to display in a listbox on the same form to see if that might have changed anything but it still remains blank. I can confirm that I've only ever tested it with .txt files as I've put no error checking in at this stage. Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `ListBox` is not for displaying text, but displaying lists (as the name suggests). If you want to display text, use a `TextBox`. Since it is likely that the file will contain multiple lines, you can set the `.Multiline` property to `True`, so that the `TextBox` will display it correctly.

Furthermore, you should use the `using statement` when dealing with `Streams`

```
Dim content As String = ""
Using textReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(openTxt.FileName)
  content = textReader.ReadToEnd
End Using
displayForm.ListBox1.Text = content
```

or simply use the `System.IO.File.ReadAllText("path to file here")` command.

Comment: Thank you very much, just swapped out the listbox with a textbox and made changes to the using part and it worked just as I would have liked.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to read the file line-by-line and populate the listbox control?

If that's the case then try this function

```
Function ReadFile(ByVal Filename As String) As String()
    Dim Sl As New List(Of String)
    Using Sr As New StreamReader(Filename)
        While Sr.Peek >= 0
            Sl.Add(Sr.ReadLine())
        End While
    End Using
    Return Sl.ToArray
End Function
```

And use like so:

```
    For Each Line As String In ReadFile("FILENAME.txt")
        ListBox1.Items.Add(Line)
    Next
```