# Read XML file structure and export to strings

Tags: xml, string, vb.net

Im trying to modify the code given in the answer to pull more information from the xml file than was originally put in but im getting some errors

[Code]

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
    Public FILENAME As String = String.Empty
    Public models As Model
    Public productionBlocks As New Panel
    Public pictureBlocks As New List(Of PictureBox)
    Public gridsinfo As CubeGrid

    Public dictCount As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()
        AddHandler Me.Load, AddressOf Form1_Load
        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

    End Sub


    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim fileloader As New OpenFileDialog
        fileloader.ShowDialog()
        FILENAME = fileloader.FileName

        models = New Model
        models.Load(FILENAME)

        Dim blockNames As List(Of String) = models.print.Select(Function(x) x.cubes.Select(Function(y) y.cubeBlocks.Select(Function(z) z.SubtypeName)).SelectMany(Function(y) y).ToList()).FirstOrDefault()
        Dim gridSizeEnumerator As String = models.print.Select(Function(x) gridsinfo.gridSizeEnum).ToString
        dictCount = blockNames.GroupBy(Function(x) x).ToDictionary(Function(x) x.Key, Function(y) y.Count)
        Dim display As String = models.print2.Select(Function(x) x.cubes.Select(Function(y) y.displayname)).SelectMany(Function(y) y).ToString().First()
        Dim enumer As String = models.print3.Select(Function(x) x.cubes.Select(Function(y) y.enumerator)).SelectMany(Function(y) y).ToString().First()


        For Each item In dictCount
            InfluenceListBox1.AddItem(item)
        Next item



        For Each key As String In dictCount.Keys.AsEnumerable()
            TextBox1.Text = "subTypeName = '{0}', count = '{1}'" + key.ToString + dictCount(key).ToString + Environment.NewLine
        Next key



        If InfluenceListBox1.lstbox.Items.Item(1).ToString.Contains("Large") Then
            InfluenceTextBox1.Text = "Grid Size: Large Ship"
        ElseIf InfluenceListBox1.lstbox.Items.Item(1).ToString.Contains("Small") Then
            InfluenceTextBox1.Text = "Grid Size: Small Ship"
        End If

        InfluenceTextBox2.Text = "Grid Owner: " + display.ToString
        InfluenceTextBox3.Text = "Grid Size Enumerator: " + enumer.ToString
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class Model
    Public print As New List(Of Model)
    Public print2 As New List(Of Model)
    Public print3 As New List(Of Model)

    Public _type As String
    Public _id As ID
    Public _display As String
    Public _display1 As String
    Public displayname As String
    Public enumerator As String
    Public cubes As List(Of CubeGrid)
    Public info As String

    Public Sub Load(filename As String)

        Dim reader As New StreamReader(filename)

        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(reader)
        Dim firstNode As XElement = doc.FirstNode
        Dim xsiNs = firstNode.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("xsi")
        Dim drawingTypes = firstNode.Elements.FirstOrDefault()
        Dim drawingType = drawingTypes.Elements.FirstOrDefault()
        Dim drawingStr = drawingType.Name.LocalName

        print = doc.Descendants(drawingStr).Select(Function(x) New Model() With {
           ._type = x.Attribute(xsiNs + "type"), ._id = x.Elements("Id").Select(Function(y) New ID() With {
                                              .type = y.Attribute("Type"),
                                              .subtype = y.Attribute("Subtype")
                                          }).FirstOrDefault(),
           .cubes = x.Descendants("CubeGrid").Select(Function(y) New CubeGrid() With {
                                                      .id = y.Element("EntityId"),
                                                      .persistentFlags = y.Element("PersistentFlags"),
                                                      .position = y.Descendants("Position").Select(Function(z) New location() With {
                                                        .x = CType(z.Attribute("x"), Double),
                                                        .y = CType(z.Attribute("y"), Double),
                                                        .z = CType(z.Attribute("z"), Double)
                                                      }).FirstOrDefault(),
                                                      .forward = y.Descendants("Forward").Select(Function(z) New location() With {
                                                        .x = CType(z.Attribute("x"), Double),
                                                        .y = CType(z.Attribute("y"), Double),
                                                        .z = CType(z.Attribute("z"), Double)
                                                      }).FirstOrDefault(),
                                                      .up = y.Descendants("Up").Select(Function(z) New location() With {
                                                        .x = CType(z.Attribute("x"), Double),
                                                        .y = CType(z.Attribute("y"), Double),
                                                        .z = CType(z.Attribute("z"), Double)
                                                      }).FirstOrDefault(),
                                                      .orientation = y.Descendants("Orientation").Select(Function(z) New location() With {
                                                        .w = CType(z.Element("W"), Double),
                                                        .x = CType(z.Element("X"), Double),
                                                        .y = CType(z.Element("Y"), Double),
                                                        .z = CType(z.Element("Z"), Double)
                                                      }).FirstOrDefault(),
                                                      .cubeBlocks = y.Descendants("MyObjectBuilder_CubeBlock").Select(Function(z) New CubeBlock() With {
                                                        .SubtypeName = z.Element("SubtypeName")
                                                      }).ToList()
                                                  }).ToList()
        }).ToList()

        print2 = doc.Descendants(drawingStr).Select(Function(x) New Model() With {
            .cubes = x.Descendants("CubeGrid").Select(Function(y) New CubeGrid() With {
                .displayname = y.Element("DisplayName")
            }).ToList()
        }).ToList()

        print3 = doc.Descendants(drawingStr).Select(Function(x) New Model() With {
        .cubes = x.Descendants("CubeGrid").Select(Function(y) New CubeGrid() With {
            .enumerator = y.Element("GridSizeEnum")
            }).ToList()
        }).ToList()
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class ID
    Public type As String
    Public subtype As String
End Class
Public Class CubeGrid
    Public id As String
    Public persistentFlags As String
    Public position As location
    Public forward As location
    Public up As location
    Public orientation As location
    Public cubeBlocks As List(Of CubeBlock)

    Public displayname As String
    Public enumerator As String
End Class
Public Class location
    Public w As Double
    Public x As Double
    Public y As Double
    Public z As Double
End Class
Public Class CubeBlock
    Public SubtypeName As String
    Public username As String
End Class
```

[/code]

The error is when converting the label text to the display-name from string throwing an invalid casting exception i would also like to add more items such as the Grid name and grid size enumerator so i can remove the ifcontains() methods on the listbox any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please take a bit of time to read the help docs on [asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are _so_ many questions on StackOverflow already that address what you are looking for.  Search, attempt, then ask about _specifics_ if you run into a snag.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25529873/vb-net-reading-from-a-txt-file-and-displaying-the-contents and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286505/how-to-find-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-substring-within-a-string-vb-net

Comment: Well ive been using those and im trying a different method using string splitting and ive read alot of topics... 
Taking a string like this:
Conveyor Junction 391 204,884.00 Kg 02:36:24.00
and splitting it into 3 new strings.

Comment: Perhaps provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Of what you have so far so that we can help.

Comment: I managed to sort out a work around by splitting the string and sending it to a listbox and using the lisbox.items() selector to select the correct string, this will work for now but the XML reader/counter is the goal as so people can just import straight from the host program instead of clicking a button then saving a text file then loading it.
INPUT: https://pastebin.com/FZzVzRrk
CODE: https://pastebin.com/dV6BShQY
OUTPUT: http://imgur.com/a/WXE1j

This rework led me to a new problem the 2/4th ones show incorrect values even tho when its in the listbox the index of val is 1 so :/ wip

Comment: btw the issue im having is that the input file is over 300k lines and when i try to load it with this method im using its giving a lockup error i dont remember its specific name atm but im currently trying to find a solution.

Comment: using .readtoend() makes it read instantly and the search function works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this as a start

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Public models As Model
    Public productionBlocks As New Panel
    Public pictureBlocks As New List(Of PictureBox)

    Public dictCount As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()
        'AddHandler Me.Load, AddressOf Form1_Load
        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

    End Sub


    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        models = New Model
        models.Load(FILENAME)

        Dim blockNames As List(Of String) = models.print.Select(Function(x) x.cubes.Select(Function(y) y.cubeBlocks.Select(Function(z) z.SubtypeName)).SelectMany(Function(y) y).ToList()).FirstOrDefault()

        dictCount = blockNames.GroupBy(Function(x) x).ToDictionary(Function(x) x.Key, Function(y) y.Count)


    End Sub
End Class
Public Class Model
    Public print As New List(Of Model)

    Public _type As String
    Public _id As ID
    Public cubes As List(Of CubeGrid)

    Public Sub Load(filename As String)

        Dim reader As New StreamReader(filename)

        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(reader)
        Dim firstNode As XElement = doc.FirstNode
        Dim xsiNs = firstNode.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("xsi")
        Dim drawingTypes = firstNode.Elements.FirstOrDefault()
        Dim drawingType = drawingTypes.Elements.FirstOrDefault()
        Dim drawingStr = drawingType.Name.LocalName
        print = doc.Descendants(drawingStr).Select(Function(x) New Model() With { _
           ._type = x.Attribute(xsiNs + "type"), _
           ._id = x.Elements("Id").Select(Function(y) New ID() With { _
                                              .type = y.Attribute("Type"), _
                                              .subtype = y.Attribute("Subtype") _
                                          }).FirstOrDefault(), _
           .cubes = x.Descendants("CubeGrid").Select(Function(y) New CubeGrid() With { _
                                                      .id = y.Element("EntityId"),
                                                      .persistentFlags = y.Element("PersistentFlags"),
                                                      .gridSizeEnum = y.Element("GridSizeEnum"),
                                                      .position = y.Descendants("Position").Select(Function(z) New location() With { _
                                                        .x = CType(z.Attribute("x"), Double), _
                                                        .y = CType(z.Attribute("y"), Double), _
                                                        .z = CType(z.Attribute("z"), Double) _
                                                      }).FirstOrDefault(), _
                                                      .forward = y.Descendants("Forward").Select(Function(z) New location() With { _
                                                        .x = CType(z.Attribute("x"), Double), _
                                                        .y = CType(z.Attribute("y"), Double), _
                                                        .z = CType(z.Attribute("z"), Double) _
                                                      }).FirstOrDefault(), _
                                                      .up = y.Descendants("Up").Select(Function(z) New location() With { _
                                                        .x = CType(z.Attribute("x"), Double), _
                                                        .y = CType(z.Attribute("y"), Double), _
                                                        .z = CType(z.Attribute("z"), Double) _
                                                      }).FirstOrDefault(),
                                                      .orientation = y.Descendants("Orientation").Select(Function(z) New location() With { _
                                                        .w = CType(z.Element("W"), Double), _
                                                        .x = CType(z.Element("X"), Double), _
                                                        .y = CType(z.Element("Y"), Double), _
                                                        .z = CType(z.Element("Z"), Double) _
                                                      }).FirstOrDefault(), _
                                                      .cubeBlocks = y.Descendants("MyObjectBuilder_CubeBlock").GroupBy(Function(z) CType(z.Element("SubtypeName"), String)).Select(Function(z) New CubeBlock() With { _
                                                        .SubtypeName = z.Key,
                                                        .count = z.Count
                                                      }).ToList()
                                                  }).ToList()
        }).ToList()

    End Sub
End Class
Public Class ID
    Public type As String
    Public subtype As String
End Class
Public Class CubeGrid
    Public id As String
    Public persistentFlags As String
    Public gridSizeEnum As String
    Public position As location
    Public forward As location
    Public up As location
    Public orientation As location
    Public cubeBlocks As List(Of CubeBlock)
End Class
Public Class location
    Public w As Double
    Public x As Double
    Public y As Double
    Public z As Double
End Class
Public Class CubeBlock
    Public SubtypeName As String
    Public count As Integer
End Class
```

---

Answers to questions

---

1)
Now how can i use this 'dictCount

```
For Each key As String In dictCount.Keys.AsEnumerable()
            Console.WriteLine("subTypeName = '{0}', count = '{1}'", key, dictCount(key))
        Next key
```

---

2) what i did wring

```
Dim print2 = doc.Descendants(drawingStr).Select(Function(x) New Model() With { _
                                                            .cubes = x.Descendants("CubeGrid").Select(Function(y) New CubeGrid() With { _
                                                                                                                .displayname = y.Element("DisplayName") _
                                                                                                         }).ToList() _
                                                        }).ToList()
```

Comment: I modified code to use a group by so the CubeBlocks are combined by name.